# Does receive mode ReceiveAndDelete for Azure Service Bus Topics delete for all subscribers or current subscriber only?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

This link: [Receive and Delete Message (Destructive Read)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/receive-and-delete-message-destructive-read)

> This operation receives a message from a queue or subscription, and removes the message from that queue or subscription in one atomic operation.

States from subscription.

I am debugging an issue where Subscribers are not receiving messages and knowing for cetain the above helps eliminate sources to investigate.

Comment: If your subscribers are listening to the same subscription, then the message will be deleted for all of them. However if your subscribers are listening to different subscriptions, then the message will be deleted for only the subscriber which is listening to the subscription on which you called this method.

Comment: Thats what I thought.  TY